# Why is \$A=10V\$, not \$-30V ?\$

Tags: voltage

Question asks me the voltage of \$V_{AB}\$ and \$V_{CD}\$,

\$V_{AB}=A-B\$ and \$V_{CD}=C-D\$, the solution tells me \$V_{AB}=A-B=10-20=-10\$,\$V_{CD}=30+10-20=20\$

I want to ask

1. Why is \$A=10V\$, not \$-30V ?\$
2. Why is \$V_{CD}=30+10-20=20\$, not \$V_{CD}=30+10+20=60\$?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTni2Q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, notice that there is zero current flowing in the circuit, therefore there is zero voltage drop across each of the resistors.

1. \$\small V_{AB}\$ is the voltage of A above B, so start at B and call this 0V. To travel from A to B, you must first go down through 20 V, and then up through 10 V, hence: \$\small V_{AB}=-20+10=-10\:V\$
2. \$\small V_{CD}\$ is the voltage of C above D, so start at D and call this 0V. To travel from D to C, you must first go down through 20 V, and then up through 10 V, then up through 30 V, hence: \$\small V_{CD}=-20+10+30=20\:V\$

Answer (score 1):

You have to pay attention to the signs of the voltages.

Look from A to B and count the voltage from 0V.

Across R1 is 0, so we have 0V at the next node

Across V1 is -10V so we have -10V at the next node

Across V2 is +20V so we have +10V at B

Similarly Vcd is -30 + 0 -10  + 20 + 0 = -20, which disagrees with your solution, so either it's Vdc or the answer given is incorrect.

Comment: "Across R1 is 0, so we have 0V at the next node" so you mean A=0V?

Comment: Yes, the node you start with is 0V, because that's your reference point. Just as ground often is used as a reference.

Comment: why should we start from 0V?there is a voltage source near A

Comment: The voltage is measured from A, for Vab. If you were using a multimeter, you would put the negative probe on the node marked A. By definition it is 0V.

Answer (score 1):

Voltage is always measured between two points. So Va = 10V does not make much sense except when a GND is defined somewhere and all measurements are implicitly referenced against that. But there is no GND in your circuit.

Vab or Vac, and Vdb are okay because it tells you which two points you are measuring between.

In this case, since you are only interested in voltages  measured between points A, B, C, D, if you want to talk about Va, Vb, Vc, or Vd alone you have to define a GND yourself. It can be anywhere because when talking about a voltage between points A, B, C, and D the GND you chose will cancel out so it doesn't matter where it is.

For example, after you have chosen some point to be GND then you can go:

$$Vab = (Va - GND) - (Vb - GND) = Va - Vb $$

with Va and Vb implicitly being measured against GND. Then you can talk about just Va, Vb, Vc, or Vd.

But if you have chosen no GND or no GND has been defined in your circuit you then saying Va, Vb, Vc, or Vd has no meaning.

That means the way you asked your question cannot be answered. You can only ask about the voltage between any two points of A, B, C, or D. But you can't actually ask for the voltage at point A, B, C or D alone.

---

There is no current flowing in the circuit because it is an open-loop. Therefore the resistors have zero current in them and according to V=IR, that means there is no voltage drop across the resistor so the voltage on both sides each resistor are the same. Therefore:

$$Vca = 30V$$
$$Vac = -30V$$
$$Vdb=Vbd=0V$$
$$Vba = 10V $$
$$Vab=-10V$$
$$Vcd = 20V$$

It seems you have not noticed that V2 is in the opposite direction of V1 and V3.

Comment: can you explain why is the Vab =-10?

Comment: @shineele Move from A to B along the wire and keep track of the voltages as you pass through V1 and V2, and notice that V1 and V2 are facing different directions. Both your questions revolve around V2 being in the opposite direction of V1 and V3 but you somehow keep ignoring this fact. You keep looking at the voltages written beside them but not actually looking at the way the DC source is facing.